# Ignore all files in folder grunt concat

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I am trying to concatenate all js files in the root and in any other folders of my app, but ignore any files in the `node_modules` folder. For some reason this setup still takes the node modules, too:

```
 concat: {
            dist: {
                src: ['*.js', '**/*.js', '!node_modules/*.js'],
                dest: 'concat.js'
            }
        },
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Same result. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To negate matching the whole `node_modules` directory use this glob pattern:

```js
'!node_modules/**/*.js'
```

1. You probably need to also negate your `Gruntfile.js` too, in which case you can include multiple `!` negation patterns.
2. Also, as `concat.js` is being written to the projects root directory, you'll need to negate that too to exclude that on subsequent runs of the task.

For example:

```js
concat: {
  dist: {
    src: ['*.js', '**/*.js', '!node_modules/**/*.js', '!Gruntfile.js', '!concat.js'],
    dest: 'concat.js'
  }
},
```